# Symfony & Doctrine: Optional foreign key

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

Without scrutinizing why I want this (it may sound like a bad approach, but I have good reason) I want to know if there is a way in the standard-framework-edition 3.1+ to create a relational association to an entity that may not exist...

Firstly I do realize this determines the schema and that's fine. So if an entity does not exist, it doesn't create a foreign key and the field is always null, or if the target entity does exist, it creates the foreign key and the field works like a normal association...

Secondly, this only changes project to project, and may change down the line as an update to which I realize a manual schema update could be necessary.

Preferably without 3rd party bundle dependencies... hoping for the standard framework to do this,

Anybody?
Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I am using annotations in my entities with doctrine ORM

**Furthermore**

The simplest version of why I am doing this is because certain bundles are optional project-to-project, and bundle A may make use of entities in bundle B only if it is present. I have considered using services and if container->has then container->get, or the XML on-invalid="null" approach, but that doesn't address property persistence. I was happy with storing a non-mapped value as a custom relational field, which is fine, just lengthier and wondered if perhaps there was a way Doctrine could ignore a missing targetEntity...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will keep the other answer as it responds to the question for a 'nullable association target' `live data`.

This is the answer for a 'nullable association target' `meta data` which is a different thing.

OP asks to provide a `targetEntity` in the metadata which cannot exist in his case, e.g. is not there in a different bundle (or whatever OP's mysterious reason might be).

In that case I recommend to build upon Doctrine's [TargetEntityListener](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html) which is able to resolve the targetEntity during runtime and `targetEntity` can be set to an Abstract Class or an Interface:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Acme\InvoiceBundle\Model\InvoiceSubjectInterface")
 * @var InvoiceSubjectInterface
 */
protected $subject;
```

`InvoiceSubjectInterface` will then be replaced during runtime by a specific class provided by config e.g.:

```
# app/config/config.yml
doctrine:
    # ...
    orm:
        # ...
        resolve_target_entities:
            Acme\InvoiceBundle\Model\InvoiceSubjectInterface: AppBundle\Entity\Customer
```

So this should be eiter an extendable behaviour for providing `no class` or implementing an own solution.

Comment: This is a great suggestion thanks, will explore and see if it suits my needs... you are a legend sir

Answer (score 3):

Hm, perhaps I misunderstand your question, but this sounds like a normal 'nullable' association to me?

Create your assocation via annotation:

```
/**
 *
 * @var Child
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Child")
 */
private $child;
```

and use

```
setChild(Child $child = null)
{
  $this->child = $child;
}
```

as a Setter to allow nullable values.

And your getter might look like:

```
getChild()
{
  return $this->child;
}
```

In case there isn't any `child` it will return null.

Comment: Nope, not quite that simple, the entity in targetEntity= may or may not exist, and if it doesn't, an exception is understandably raised, so I want the ability for doctrine to ignore that...?

Comment: so you'll have to rephrase your question and indeed explain why you want to do that. to me it does not make sense at all. why not creating the entity and if you don't want to use it, simple don't use it.

Comment: My question explains that the entity may not exist, and it also says there's no need to scrutinize why I'm doing it, the questions is, can it be done... sorry to be blunt, but it's all there

Comment: have a look here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know about it. But it's still going to fail, because on the case that `AppBundle\Entity\Customer` doesn't exist, I am still going to get an exception. Added some info to my question, to vaguely explain myself... hopefully makes sense...

Comment: The Listener is public, you can either extend from it or just use the implementation as a base for your own - this is the way to go.

Comment: LBA, i didn't read the link thoroughly thanks again, it seems you're a legend, so please post it as an answer and I'll upvote and mark it... thanks again ;)